# push new object into flatlist data array

Tags: javascript, react-native, push

I'm trying to make a chat app, I have a flatlist, my flatlist data comes from apis, I'm  going to push my new message to this flatlist and show my component with new data.
but the problem is my list data doesn't change and it doesn't show my new message,
is there anybody who can help me?

```
useEffect(() => {
    chatHistoryData()
}, [])

let chatHistoryData = async () => {
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(false);

        let res = await axios.get(`https://call.darmankade.com/report/${reserveHash}`);
        if (res && res.data) {
            let filterChatData = res.data.filter((x: any) => x.type != 4);
            console.log("chat data: ", filterChatData)
            setChatData(filterChatData);
            setLoading(false);
            setError(false);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('loading consult history failed: ', error);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
    }
}
```

my flatlist and textinput component

```
<FlatList
   ref={chatList}
   data={chatData}
   keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.index}
   onContentSizeChange={() => chatList.current.scrollToEnd()}
   ListFooterComponent={() => { return <View style={{ height: verticalScale(20) }} /> }}
       renderItem={(data: any) => {
                  return <MessageBody
                                patientSide={data.item.side == consultSides.Patient}
                                doctorSide={data.item.side == consultSides.Doctor}
                                textMsg={data.item.type == 1}
                                hasImage={data.item.type == 3}
                                hasVoice={data.item.type == 2}
                                content={data.item.content}
                                messageTime={data.item.date.slice(11, 16)}
                            />
                        }}
                    />

<MessageInput
   inputValue={messageTxt}
   inputOnchangeText={setMessageTxt}
   startRecording={sendMessage}
 />
```

my send button

```
let sendMessage = useCallback(() => {
    let newChatData = [...chatData]
    newChatData.push({
        connectionId: "9f5dssd_qGJUYhHMDRnm05g5yw",
        content: "salam niloo",
        date: "2020-10-31T12:55:03.076",
        side: consultSides.Doctor,
        type: consultMessages.text,
        userAgent: null
    })

    setChatData(newChatData)

}, [messageTxt])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.push` you can do the following,

```
let sendMessage = useCallback(() => {
let newChatData = [...chatData, {
        connectionId: "9f5dssd_qGJUYhHMDRnm05g5yw",
        content: "salam niloo",
        date: "2020-10-31T12:55:03.076",
        side: consultSides.Doctor,
        type: consultMessages.text,
        userAgent: null
    }];

    setChatData(newChatData)

}, [messageTxt])
```

Comment: still i can not see my new message in my flatlist